# Modify Ionic barcode scanner plugin to read digits

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I have used the [ion-scanner](https://github.com/adamweeks/ion-scanner) plugin for the Ionic framework to read barcodes and it works fine. Now my question is can the barcode library be modified to automatically scan for digits instead of barcodes?

The barcodescanner.js script looks like this,

```
...
function BarcodeScanner() {

/**
 * Encoding constants.
 *
 * @type Object
 */
this.Encode = {
    TEXT_TYPE: "TEXT_TYPE",
    EMAIL_TYPE: "EMAIL_TYPE",
    PHONE_TYPE: "PHONE_TYPE",
    SMS_TYPE: "SMS_TYPE"
    //  CONTACT_TYPE: "CONTACT_TYPE",  // TODO:  not implemented, requires passing a Bundle class from Javascript to Java
    //  LOCATION_TYPE: "LOCATION_TYPE" // TODO:  not implemented, requires passing a Bundle class from Javascript to Java
};

/**
 * Barcode format constants, defined in ZXing library.
 *
 * @type Object
 */
this.format = {
    "all_1D": 61918,
    "aztec": 1,
    "codabar": 2,
    "code_128": 16,
    "code_39": 4,
    "code_93": 8,
    "data_MATRIX": 32,
    "ean_13": 128,
    "ean_8": 64,
    "itf": 256,
    "maxicode": 512,
    "msi": 131072,
    "pdf_417": 1024,
    "plessey": 262144,
    "qr_CODE": 2048,
    "rss_14": 4096,
    "rss_EXPANDED": 8192,
    "upc_A": 16384,
    "upc_E": 32768,
    "upc_EAN_EXTENSION": 65536
}; //More code after
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.